# ASP.NET Reading xml with FileStream (FileMode.Open) -> System.UnauthorizedAccessException

Tags: asp.net, permissions, filestream, file-permissions

I have a website which reads settings from an xml config file (I'm using a .config extension). I open the file like so:

```
XmlSerializer xmlSerializer = new XmlSerializer(typeof(T));

using (Stream fs = new FileStream(filename, FileMode.Open))
{
     configSettings = xmlSerializer.Deserialize(fs) as MyConfigSettings;
}
```

I only need read access to the file, but for some reason I'm getting a System.UnauthorizedAccessException unless I give write permissions on the file. This is something I don't wan't to do, and it's only required for the code to read the file.

Why does this happen, and what should I change to stop this happening?

Comment: You need to accept an answer if you like people to help you again. I believe jpmc26 has the best answer.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The FileStream constructor you are using opens the file with both read and write permissions. See the Remarks section of the [documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/47ek66wy.aspx):

> For constructors without a FileAccess parameter, if the mode parameter is set to Append, Write is the default access. Otherwise, the access is set to ReadWrite.

You need to use the [three argument constructor](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/tyhc0kft.aspx) with FileAccess.Read as the third argument.

Like this:

```
using (Stream fs = new FileStream(filename, FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read))
```

Comment: Thanks. I ended up using a StreamReader which did the same job.

Answer (score 2):

I resolved the issue using a StreamReader instead:

```
XmlSerializer xmlSerializer = new XmlSerializer(typeof(T));

using (StreamReader reader = new StreamReader(filename))
{
   configSettings= (MyConfigSettings)xmlSerializer.Deserialize(reader);
}
```

Comment: This does not answer the question, it just solves your own problem.

Comment: Unless my compiler is different to everyone else's then it's a valid answer to the question Mr Panko.